# Valid xml parsed into a string?

Tags: xml, groovy

Is it a bug that parsing this XML:

```
new XmlSlurper().parseText('''
<xml>
    <ToUserName><![CDATA[gh_f19b154f8baf]]></ToUserName>
    <FromUserName><![CDATA[oidkW1WsewC7wiyN4ET1-Dsn52oQ]]></FromUserName>
    <CreateTime>1491921778</CreateTime>
    <MsgType><![CDATA[text]]></MsgType>
    <Content><![CDATA[ggg]]></Content>
    <MsgId>6407755245131660376</MsgId>
</xml>
''')
```

results into: `gh_f19b154f8bafoidkW1WsewC7wiyN4ET1-Dsn52oQ1491921778textggg6407755245131660376`?

Comment: No, why? It just how `toString` works for object received as a result of parsing XML with `XmlSlurper`. What do you expect, need?

Comment: Opal, you right, in the logs I just didn't see what kind of object that is. Can you please post an answer. I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As result of invoking `parseText` on `XmlParser` an instance of [Node](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/Node.html) is returned. What you see is a string representation of the mentioned `Node`. Printing out the whole `Node` doesn't make much sense, especially for big XML files. Instead you can navigate to particular values and print them out.